# SQLite Insert or Replace Where

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have a table with 3 columns, ID, Description and Key where ID is not a primary key!
What i want is to insert or update/replace a current record.
Example:
decryptionKeys 
ID     Description    Key
999    Birthday       24.12.1988

I tried this but it won't work:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO decryptionKeys VALUES ("999","Birthday","25.12.1988") WHERE ID="999" AND Description="Birthday"
```

Comment: Is there any unique key on the table?  Perhaps a combination of id and description?

Comment: I could implement this! Would it help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

leave thr where clause

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO decryptionKeys VALUES ("999","Birthday","25.12.1988")
```

Comment: This only works if you have an unique key on the table! But now it works! Thanks!

Comment: What Manu says is very important!