# SQLiteException syntax error unclear

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax-error, android-sqlite

I get

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: `insert or replace into taeglich (datum, a, b, c, d) values ('29.4.2017', '10 ml f\n', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0') WHERE datum = '29.4.2017';`

Do you see the syntax error?

Comment: share complete logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Insert or Replace Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573215/sqlite-insert-or-replace-where)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **WHERE** clauses

```
insert or replace into taeglich VALUES ('29.4.2017', '10 ml f\n', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0');
```